# Sidescroller game with customer gestures on unity

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, unity-game-engine

I was wondering what turotials are out there for creating games for the windows phone? What I'm trying to do is create a sidescroller game which will allow gesture control. Such as if you click on an enemy, it moves to them then attacks them. If you swipe with one finger, it does one move. If you swipe with 2 fingers, it does another. If you make a circle, it does another move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of community help on the topics of touch inputs, you'll either have to write your own custom input handling class for gesture detection or purchase an asset store package that does the same.

[You could start here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Touch.html)